# Let $z_1 = k + 1 + i(k − 1)$ and $z_2 = 2k − ik$ be to complex numbers, whats the value for $k$ if $\frac{z_1}{z_2} $is real number?

Tags: calculus, analysis

> Let $z_1 = k + 1 + i(k − 1)$ and $z_2 = 2k − ik$ be to complex numbers, whats the value for $k$ if $\dfrac{z_1}{z_2} $is real number?

Answer is $\dfrac13$, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: just set imaginary part to zero

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Note that $\frac{z_1}{z_2}=\frac{z_1\overline{z_2}}{|z_2|^2}$, and in the latter the denominator is a real number (if $k$ is real).